# how to close fragments to see activity below using OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

so the way my app is created is i have my `MapsActivity` which is loaded when the app starts, and i have a bottom navigation widget that has 3 icons and it's selected on the first icon by default (which i've named Map). the two other icons when selected are fragments.

I'm trying to close the fragment when i click on the Map icon in the navigation widget, since that is essentially my main activity.

[image: this is what i have]

now i'm stuck and can't get back to my `MapsActivity` because i don't know how to close the fragment

**MapsActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    getAutoCompleteSearchResults()
}

...

private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {item->
    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.nav_map -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "map pressed")
            // if there's a fragment, close it
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.nav_A -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fragment A pressed")
            replaceFragment(FragmentA())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.nav_B -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fragment B pressed")
            replaceFragment(FragmentB())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

...

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the currently attached fragment and detach it from the activity:

```
private fun detachFragment(fragment: Fragment){
val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
...
```

And have a method for checking the visible fragment:

```
private fun getVisibleFragment(): Fragment? {
val fragmentManager = MapsActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
val fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments()
if(fragments != null) {
    for (fragment: Fragment in fragments) {
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
            return fragment
        }
    return null
    }
}
...
```

Then use it inside your MainActivity:

```
...
when(item.itemId){
    R.id.nav_map -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "map pressed")
        // if there's a fragment, close it
        val visibleFragment = getVisibleFragment()
        if(visibleFragment != null && visibleFragment.getId() != R.id.map) {
            detachFragment(visibleFragment)
        }

        return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
    }
...
```

Comment: I tried that out (had fix fix your `getVisibleFragment()` function a bit. So now when i click on the map icon in the navigation bar the fragment goes away, however nowi can't move around the MapsActivity, the google maps doesn't scroll around anymore, but the search bar still works.

Comment: Sorry about the fix. Am new to Kotlin lang. What about the other navbars are they working fine? This could be as a result of the maps activity destabilizing after the fragment is detached.

Comment: Try adding ```val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)``` after the `detachFragment(fragment)` see if that resolves this

Comment: No worries, i litterally just started Kotlin like 2 days ago. My other fragments work fine, i can switch between them and i set up a button in each of them and they all respond onClick. It's just the MapsActivity that isn't working after detaching the a fragment. I've added those 2 lines after `fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment)` in the `detachFragment` function, but it crashes when i click on the map icon after after clicking on a fragment icon. `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: I think i know why my map fragment is "freezing" every time i detach my fragments. It's because in my `getVisibleFragment` function, i'm looping through ALL the fragments including my `supportMapFragment`. How do i check in the for loop if the fragment is the `supportMapFragment?`

Comment: I've editted the code in the `R.id.nav_map`'s case to check for the id of the fragment if it's the map fragment. See if this works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186300/discussion-between-murageden-and-barcode).